# Problem with defining linear programming constraints

Tags: math, optimization, data-science, linear-programming

Me and my friend are trying to implement a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11573-016-0823-7) and the last step requires solving a linear programming problem to get the final result. We are not so familiar with LP so i'd like to ask for your help.

Here's the function which is based on the [PROFSET model](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.507.2229&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[image: function IMG]

and here's the proposed constraints

(1)

[image: constraint IMG]

(2)

[image: constraint IMG]

where:

1. Pa and Qi are the binary decision variables
2. J are all the available categories
3. F are sets of frequent categories
4. Φ is the total number of selected categories

Constraint (1) actually says that Qi is 1 if category i is included in some itemset A where Pa = 1

Basically, we are trying to use some common open source lp solvers (like joptimizer) but we dont know
how to define those constraints, especially those that define set inclusion rules. Most of those solvers
seem to accept just inequalities.

So, do you have any idea about how to define those constraints? Maybe transform them to inequalities or
something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not about [tag:java], so I have removed this tag for you.  That way you won't attract Java experts who won't be able to help you with this problem.

Comment: Are F and the items in A constant or are they also optimized? (Haven't looked at the paper).

Comment: They are constant. F contains precomputed frequent itemsets A and then Pa and Qi are used as decision variables in order to maximize the function.

Comment: Then number (1) is actually a number of constraints. For each element in the respective set, you set up one constraint. How exactly you do this depends on the library you use. And all libraries should be able to handle the equality constraint directly. Alternatively, you can model it as two inequalities (<= and >=).

Comment: Thank you very much, it starts to make sense now. Could you give me an example of the resulting constraints from a set A = {a, b, c}?

Comment: That would then be `{ Qa >= PA, Qb >= PA, Qc >= PA, Qa + Qb + Qc = Phi }`.

Comment: Thank you again, i appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming (in the sense used hereabouts) until OP and his (?) chum figure out the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A constraint that is written as an equality can be also written as two inequalities.
e.g.

- A*x=b is the same as
- A*x<=b and A*x>=b

In order to write such a LP there are two ways.

1. To hardcode it, meaning writing everything in code for example in Java.
2. Write it the mathematical way in a "language" called AMPL: https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/ For the second way you don't really need to know a programming language. AMPL transforms magically your LP into code and feeds it to a solver e.g. commercial: CPLEX, Gurobi (academic license available) or open source: GLPK. AMPL provides also an online platform that you can provide your model as .mod file and data as .dat files.

If you still want to hardcode your LP GLPK has nice examples e.g. in JAVA:

```
public class Lp {
    //  Minimize z = -.5 * x1 + .5 * x2 - x3 + 1
    //
    //  subject to
    //  0.0 <= x1 - .5 * x2 <= 0.2
    //  -x2 + x3 <= 0.4
    //  where,
    //  0.0 <= x1 <= 0.5
    //  0.0 <= x2 <= 0.5
    //  0.0 <= x3 <= 0.5

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    glp_prob lp;
    glp_smcp parm;
    SWIGTYPE_p_int ind;
    SWIGTYPE_p_double val;
    int ret;

    try {
        // Create problem
        lp = GLPK.glp_create_prob();
        System.out.println("Problem created");
        GLPK.glp_set_prob_name(lp, "myProblem");

        // Define columns
        GLPK.glp_add_cols(lp, 3);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_name(lp, 1, "x1");
        GLPK.glp_set_col_kind(lp, 1, GLPKConstants.GLP_CV);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 1, GLPKConstants.GLP_DB, 0, .5);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_name(lp, 2, "x2");
        GLPK.glp_set_col_kind(lp, 2, GLPKConstants.GLP_CV);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 2, GLPKConstants.GLP_DB, 0, .5);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_name(lp, 3, "x3");
        GLPK.glp_set_col_kind(lp, 3, GLPKConstants.GLP_CV);
        GLPK.glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 3, GLPKConstants.GLP_DB, 0, .5);

        // Create constraints

        // Allocate memory
        ind = GLPK.new_intArray(3);
        val = GLPK.new_doubleArray(3);

        // Create rows
        GLPK.glp_add_rows(lp, 2);

        // Set row details
        GLPK.glp_set_row_name(lp, 1, "c1");
        GLPK.glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 1, GLPKConstants.GLP_DB, 0, 0.2);
        GLPK.intArray_setitem(ind, 1, 1);
        GLPK.intArray_setitem(ind, 2, 2);
        GLPK.doubleArray_setitem(val, 1, 1.);
        GLPK.doubleArray_setitem(val, 2, -.5);
        GLPK.glp_set_mat_row(lp, 1, 2, ind, val);

        GLPK.glp_set_row_name(lp, 2, "c2");
        GLPK.glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 2, GLPKConstants.GLP_UP, 0, 0.4);
        GLPK.intArray_setitem(ind, 1, 2);
        GLPK.intArray_setitem(ind, 2, 3);
        GLPK.doubleArray_setitem(val, 1, -1.);
        GLPK.doubleArray_setitem(val, 2, 1.);
        GLPK.glp_set_mat_row(lp, 2, 2, ind, val);

        // Free memory
        GLPK.delete_intArray(ind);
        GLPK.delete_doubleArray(val);

        // Define objective
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_name(lp, "z");
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_dir(lp, GLPKConstants.GLP_MIN);
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 0, 1.);
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 1, -.5);
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 2, .5);
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 3, -1);

        // Write model to file
        // GLPK.glp_write_lp(lp, null, "lp.lp");

        // Solve model
        parm = new glp_smcp();
        GLPK.glp_init_smcp(parm);
        ret = GLPK.glp_simplex(lp, parm);

        // Retrieve solution
        if (ret == 0) {
            write_lp_solution(lp);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The problem could not be solved");
        }

        // Free memory
        GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
    } catch (GlpkException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    ret = 1;
    }
System.exit(ret);
}

/**
 * write simplex solution
 * @param lp problem
 */
static void write_lp_solution(glp_prob lp) {
    int i;
    int n;
    String name;
    double val;

    name = GLPK.glp_get_obj_name(lp);
    val = GLPK.glp_get_obj_val(lp);
    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.print(" = ");
    System.out.println(val);
    n = GLPK.glp_get_num_cols(lp);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        name = GLPK.glp_get_col_name(lp, i);
        val = GLPK.glp_get_col_prim(lp, i);
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(" = ");
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}}
```